Puppeteer not reading environment variable for executablepath. Then launch is timing out
My code has been working fine for several months.  I recently decided to update the packages (of my debian docker by rebuilding it with the same docker file) and also updating the node modules.  No errors.  I guess that was a bad idea because I have run into some issues with puppetter.
async function processweb() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable",
//        executablePath: process.env.PUPPETEER_EXEC_PATH,
        headless: false,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--font-render-hinting=none', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"]
    });
    ...
}

puppeteer would not start because it could not find the executable path.  It would not read the PUPPETEER_EXEC_PATH environment variable.  The variable is indeed set.  I resolved this by just putting the absolute path directly in the code.
This seemed to work but then I started getting the following error on the "puppeteer.launch" line.  Note, this only happens occasionally.
Unhandled Promise: Promise {
<rejected> TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for the WS endpoint URL to appear in stdout!
 at ChromeLauncher.launch (/code/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:143:23)
 at async PuppeteerExtra.launch (/code/node_modules/puppeteer-extra/dist/index.cjs.js:128:25)
 ...

Maybe chrome is taking a really long time to launch?  I tried increasing the timeout but this is causing my code to hang since I don't handle the exception.  Therefore, I put in a try-catch block to just ignore the error and move on until I could figure out what was going on but it seems I'm not implementing it correctly
async function processweb() {
    try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable",
        headless: false,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--font-render-hinting=none', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"]
    });
    } catch (error) {
        await browser.close();
        return [];
    }

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    ...
}

This results in the following error on the browser.newPage() line everytime:
Unhandled Promise: Promise {
<rejected> ReferenceError: browser is not defined
...

I don't quite understand why.  I would expect the try block to work and "browser" to be defined or it fails and the function returns (not executing the line that is producing the error)

I would post the relevant deps in the package.json before and after the upgrade so we know what versions worked/didn't work and can reproduce the problem. 30 seconds is usually plenty for any operation. Increasing the timeout almost never helps, it just makes the root problem harder to detect. You'd need to move const browser = to browser = and use let browser; outside the try scope, but yeah, if it fails launching, .newPage() is just going to throw as well, so you need to face the root problem.

Related: node js timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for the WS endpoint URL to appear in stdout, #10556, #10792

I don't have a copy of the old package.json.  I guess I should start keeping it.
Issue was reading the env var, I'm not sure if it is related.
So "try" is in it's own "namespace"?  I expected that if the try is successful, then "browser" is defined and everything works.  If it isnt successful, the error should be caught and "return" gets executed so the ".newpage()" should not be executing thus no need to declare the variable first.  The idea was to skip and try again later.

This function is called in a loop many times (sequentially) and only happens maybe 5-10% of the time which seems different than the related ones you posted or no solution was found.  That also makes it hard to reproduce

try {} creates a block, which works like any other block in JS. let and const scope variables to blocks, so they're undefined outside of the block. I would post the new package.json and then try to recreate the old one by systematically downgrading Puppeteer until it works. This is important work to isolate the problem to a specific version(s) which you can do more easily than I can. 10% failure rate seems pretty easy to repro--just run it 10 or 20 times and you're practically guaranteed to see a failure.

ok, so far the issue hasnt happened again so I guess the 60 seconds helped.  I'll go back and try reproducing to narrow down.  I am curious why it wasnt picking up the env variable too.
